# Django's get_context_data function not working?

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I'm practicing with Django's Class Based View.

It seems like my overridden get_context_data function is not working properly, but I have no idea what is wrong :(

My code:

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^user/(?P<pk>\d+)/posts/$', UserPosts.as_view(), name='user_post'),
```

**views.py**

```
class UserPosts(ListView):
    template_name = 'app_blog/user_posts_page.html'
    context_object_name = 'post_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        self.user = get_object_or_404(User, id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return self.user.post_set.order_by('-id')
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):   
        context = super(UserPosts, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['user'] = self.user
        return context
```

**user_post_page.html**

```
{% block content %}
    <div class="main_content">
        <h2>Welcome to {{user.username}}'s User Post Page!</he>
        <ul>
        {% for post in post_list %}
            <li><a href="/blog/post/{{post.id}}/">{{post.post_title}}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

The html page correctly displays the user's post_list, BUT the h2 tag displays:

```
Welcome to 's User Post Page!
```

I'm pretty sure I passed the 'user' variable in the get_context_data function, but the html page does not displa the user.username... Any idea why this is happening :(??

Thanks

Comment: Hmm... Try to print `{{ user }}` or other fields from `User` model.

Answer (score 0):

Use another name that is not `user`. It seems like RequestContext overwrite `user` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the default [`TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS), which set the [`django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/api/#django-contrib-auth-context-processors-auth).

> If `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` contains this processor, every `RequestContext` will contain these variables:
>
> - `user` – An `auth.User` instance representing the currently logged-in user (or an `AnonymousUser` instance, if the client isn’t logged in).
> - `perms` – An instance of `django.contrib.auth.context_processors.PermWrapper`, representing the permissions that the currently logged-in user has.

So you'd better give your `user` variable another name.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers said, don't use the variable name `user`. But even more importantly, in this particular case the `ListView` is not the best generic class to use; instead, you're better off using the `DetailView`, which makes your view much simpler:

```
class UserPosts(DetailView):
    model = User
    template_name = 'app_blog/user_posts_page.html'
    context_object_name = 'listed_user'
```

The only change in your template is to use `listed_user` instead of the `user` variable. Since `DetailView` already looks into the `pk` URL argument, it will select and return the right `User` automatically.